# How filters are initialized in convnet

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, theano, keras

I read a lot of papers on convnets, but there is one thing I don't understand, how the filters in convolutional layer are initialized ?
Because, for examples, in first layer, filters should detect edges etc..
But if it randomly init, it could not be accurate ? Same for next layer and high-level features.
And an other question, what are the range of the value in those filters ?

Many thanks to you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can either initialize the filters randomly or pretrain them on some other data set.

---

Some references:

http://deeplearning.net/tutorial/lenet.html:

> Notice that a randomly initialized filter acts very much like an edge
>   detector!
>
> Note that we use the same weight initialization formula as with the
>   MLP. Weights are sampled randomly from a uniform distribution in the
>   range [-1/fan-in, 1/fan-in], where fan-in is the number of inputs to a
>   hidden unit. For MLPs, this was the number of units in the layer
>   below. For CNNs however, we have to take into account the number of
>   input feature maps and the size of the receptive fields.

http://cs231n.github.io/transfer-learning/ :

> ### Transfer Learning
>
> In practice, very few people train an entire Convolutional Network
>   from scratch (with random initialization), because it is relatively
>   rare to have a dataset of sufficient size. Instead, it is common to
>   pretrain a ConvNet on a very large dataset (e.g. ImageNet, which
>   contains 1.2 million images with 1000 categories), and then use the
>   ConvNet either as an initialization or a fixed feature extractor for
>   the task of interest. The three major Transfer Learning scenarios look
>   as follows:
>
> - **ConvNet as fixed feature extractor**. Take a ConvNet pretrained on ImageNet, remove the last fully-connected layer (this layer's outputs
>     are the 1000 class scores for a different task like ImageNet), then
>     treat the rest of the ConvNet as a fixed feature extractor for the new
>     dataset. In an AlexNet, this would compute a 4096-D vector for every
>     image that contains the activations of the hidden layer immediately
>     before the classifier. We call these features **CNN codes**. It is
>     important for performance that these codes are ReLUd (i.e. thresholded
>     at zero) if they were also thresholded during the training of the
>     ConvNet on ImageNet (as is usually the case). Once you extract the
>     4096-D codes for all images, train a linear classifier (e.g. Linear
>     SVM or Softmax classifier) for the new dataset.
> - **Fine-tuning the ConvNet**. The second strategy is to not only replace and retrain the classifier on top of the ConvNet on the new
>     dataset, but to also fine-tune the weights of the pretrained network
>     by continuing the backpropagation. It is possible to fine-tune all the
>     layers of the ConvNet, or it's possible to keep some of the earlier
>     layers fixed (due to overfitting concerns) and only fine-tune some
>     higher-level portion of the network. This is motivated by the
>     observation that the earlier features of a ConvNet contain more
>     generic features (e.g. edge detectors or color blob detectors) that
>     should be useful to many tasks, but later layers of the ConvNet
>     becomes progressively more specific to the details of the classes
>     contained in the original dataset. In case of ImageNet for example,
>     which contains many dog breeds, a significant portion of the
>     representational power of the ConvNet may be devoted to features that
>     are specific to differentiating between dog breeds.
>
> **Pretrained models**. Since modern ConvNets take 2-3 weeks to train across multiple GPUs on ImageNet, it is common to see people release
>   their final ConvNet checkpoints for the benefit of others who can use
>   the networks for fine-tuning. For example, the Caffe library has a
>   [Model Zoo](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/wiki/Model-Zoo) where people
>   share their network weights.
>
> **When and how to fine-tune?** How do you decide what type of transfer learning you should perform on a new dataset? This is a function of
>   several factors, but the two most important ones are the size of the
>   new dataset (small or big), and its similarity to the original dataset
>   (e.g. ImageNet-like in terms of the content of images and the classes,
>   or very different, such as microscope images). Keeping in mind that
>   ConvNet features are more generic in early layers and more
>   original-dataset-specific in later layers, here are some common rules
>   of thumb for navigating the 4 major scenarios:
>
> 1. *New dataset is small and similar to original dataset*. Since the data is small, it is not a good idea to fine-tune the ConvNet due to
>      overfitting concerns. Since the data is similar to the original data,
>      we expect higher-level features in the ConvNet to be relevant to this
>      dataset as well. Hence, the best idea might be to train a linear
>      classifier on the CNN codes.
> 2. *New dataset is large and similar to the original dataset*. Since we have more data, we can have more confidence that we won't overfit
>      if we were to try to fine-tune through the full network.
> 3. *New dataset is small but very different from the original dataset*. Since the data is small, it is likely best to only train a
>      linear classifier. Since the dataset is very different, it might not
>      be best to train the classifier form the top of the network, which
>      contains more dataset-specific features. Instead, it might work better
>      to train the SVM classifier from activations somewhere earlier in the
>      network.
> 4. *New dataset is large and very different from the original dataset*. Since the dataset is very large, we may expect that we can
>      afford to train a ConvNet from scratch. However, in practice it is
>      very often still beneficial to initialize with weights from a
>      pretrained model. In this case, we would have enough data and
>      confidence to fine-tune through the entire network.
>
> **Practical advice**. There are a few additional things to keep in mind when performing Transfer Learning:
>
> - *Constraints from pretrained models*. Note that if you wish to use a pretrained network, you may be slightly constrained in terms of the
>     architecture you can use for your new dataset. For example, you can't
>     arbitrarily take out Conv layers from the pretrained network. However,
>     some changes are straight-forward: Due to parameter sharing, you can
>     easily run a pretrained network on images of different spatial size.
>     This is clearly evident in the case of Conv/Pool layers because their
>     forward function is independent of the input volume spatial size (as
>     long as the strides "fit"). In case of FC layers, this still holds
>     true because FC layers can be converted to a Convolutional Layer: For
>     example, in an AlexNet, the final pooling volume before the first FC
>     layer is of size [6x6x512]. Therefore, the FC layer looking at this
>     volume is equivalent to having a Convolutional Layer that has
>     receptive field size 6x6, and is applied with padding of 0.
> - *Learning rates*. It's common to use a smaller learning rate for ConvNet weights that are being fine-tuned, in comparison to the
>     (randomly-initialized) weights for the new linear classifier that
>     computes the class scores of your new dataset. This is because we
>     expect that the ConvNet weights are relatively good, so we don't wish
>     to distort them too quickly and too much (especially while the new
>     Linear Classifier above them is being trained from random
>     initialization).
>
> ### Additional References
>
> - [CNN Features off-the-shelf: an Astounding Baseline for Recognition](http://arxiv.org/abs/1403.6382) trains SVMs on features
>     from ImageNet-pretrained ConvNet and reports several state of the art
>     results.
> - [DeCAF](http://arxiv.org/abs/1310.1531) reported similar findings in 2013. The framework in this paper (DeCAF) was a Python-based precursor to the C++ Caffe library.
> - [How transferable are features in deep neural networks?](http://arxiv.org/abs/1411.1792) studies the transfer
>     learning performance in detail, including some unintuitive findings
>     about layer co-adaptations.